# RSpec Expect Hash to include an Array of key value pairs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Still learning Rspec as a whole, so thanks for patience.

Return value is this:

```
{ supermodel: {
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'J',
    'model_attributes': [
        {attr1: 'T', attrA: 1}, 
        {attr2: 'F', attrB: 2}, 
        {attr3: 'T', attrC: 3}
        ],
    }
}
```

Trying to get an expectation that says that a hash key named 'model_attributes' contains a value of an array that includes the following key value pairs - `{attr2:F, attrB: 2}` and `{attr3: T, attrC: 3}`.

Any insight would be welcome.

Comment: your `Result of method is this..` is invalid Ruby object, double check it ;)

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://apidock.com/rspec/Spec/Mocks/ArgumentMatchers/hash_including

Comment: True @AndreyDeineko reformatted the assertion to be more ruby. Thanks!

Comment: @JoaWa i meant, that `'model_attributes': [
    {attr1: T, attrA: 1}, 
    {attr2: F, attrB: 2}, 
    {attr3: T, attrC: 3}
]` is not a valid object in Ruby. It looks almost like a hash, but it lacks braces and still would be invalid because of `T`, `F` - these will throw an `Uninitialized constant T`

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity @AndreyDeineko. Provided the big picture return sample.  Was aiming for brevity, but lacked in accuracy. Thanks for input.

Comment: @JoaWa no probs. answered. Always provide input that is a valid Ruby object. Users do not like to type things, copypasting is the way to go ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
describe 'Stuff' do
  let(:model_attributes) do
    [
      {attr1: 'T', attrA: 1}, 
      {attr2: 'F', attrB: 2}, 
      {attr3: 'T', attrC: 3}
    ]
  end
  let(:result) do
    { supermodel: 
      {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'J',
        'model_attributes': model_attributes
      }
    }
  end

  it 'has the correct model_attributes value' do
    expect(result.dig(:supermodel, :model_attributes)).to eq(model_attributes)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Andrey - ended up borrowing this strategy.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
describe 'ModelAttributes' do
  let(:model_attributes) { [{ attr1: 'T', attrA: 1 },
                            { attr2: 'F', attrB: 2 },
                            { attr3: 'T', attrC: 3 }] }

  it 'includes the required attributes' do
    expect(model_attributes).to include({ attr2:'F', attrB: 2 }, { attr3: 'T', attrC: 3 })
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In retrospect this is alot easier now. Simply traversing the hash and expecting the values was the easiest way. Refactoring ended me up in doing this:

```
supermodel[:model_attributes].each do |attr|
    expect(attr[:attrB])to be 2
end
```

Thanks for all the suggestions, led me down the right path.